# Does thermostat need to be grounded?

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, grounding

If a thermostat is connected to an air handler, which is connected to the main panel and has a ground wire, should one of the thermostat wires be connected to the ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary if you are dealing with the common 24v thermostats.  Those run on low voltage AC which does not present the same hazard (and thus reason for grounding) as line voltage.  Generally when there's an air handler, you're dealing with 24v controls.